# Como implementar um campo Choices no Django e exibir os valores no Django Template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Tentei implementar um campo Choices no Django, mas não consigui finalizar, e nem entender aonde está o problema.

Esse campo modela a FaixaSalarial como umas lista de valores, os quais devem ser mostrados no template `createVaga.html`. Meu código segue abaixo.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso resolver essa questão?

**forms.py**

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from jobconvo.models import vagaDeEmprego
from django import forms

class createVagaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = vagaDeEmprego
        fields = [
        "nameJob",
    ]

class FaixaSalarialChoice(forms.Form):
    FAIXA_SALARIAL_CHOICE = (
        (('r', 'R$1.000')),
        (('r','R$1.000 a R$2.000')),
        (('r','R$2.000 a R$3.000')),
        (('r','Acima de R$3.000')),
        )
```

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from .models import models

class vagaDeEmprego(models.Model):
    nameJob = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**createVaga.html**

```html
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="col-6 mt-4 m-auto">
    <form name="createVaga" id="createVaga" method="post" action="/lista_vagas/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="form-control mt-4" type="text" name="nameJob" id="nameJob" placeholder="Nome da vaga de emprego:" value="{{ createVagaForm }}">
        <br>
        <br>
        <select id=cbFaixaSalarial name="cbFaixaSalarial" value="{{ FaixaSalarialChoice }}">
        <option>R$1.000</option>
        <option>R$1.000 a R$2.000</option>
        <option>R$2.000 a R$3.000</option>
        <option>Acima de R$3.000</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input class="btn btn-success mt-4" type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```py
from multiprocessing import context
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from .forms import FaixaSalarialChoice, createVagaForm
from .models import vagaDeEmprego
from django.template import RequestContext

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
    
def create(request):
    return render(request, 'create.html')

def store(request):
    data = {}
    if(request.POST['password'] != request.POST['password-conf']):
        data['msg'] = 'Senha e confirmação de senha diferente!'
        data['class'] = 'alert-danger'
    else:
        user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['name'], request.POST['email'], request.POST['password'])
        user.first_name = request.POST['name']
        user.save()
        user.user_permissions.add(18)
        data['msg'] = 'Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!'
        data['class'] = 'alert-success'
    return render(request, 'create.html',data)

def painel(request):
    return render(request, 'painel.html')

def dologin(request):
    data = {}
    user = authenticate(username=request.POST['user'], password=request.POST['password'])
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/createVaga/')
    else:
        data['msg'] = 'Usuário ou Senha inválidos!'
        data['class'] = 'alert-danger'
        return render(request, 'painel.html',data)

def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard/home.html')

def logouts(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/painel/')

def changePassword(request):
    user = User.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
    user.set_password(request.POST['password'])
    user.save()
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/painel/')

def createVaga(request):
    data = {}
    data['createVaga'] = createVagaForm()
    return render(request, 'createVaga.html', data)

def createVagaSalarial(request):
    data = {}
    data['cbFaixaSalarial'] = FaixaSalarialChoice()
    return render(request, "home.html", data)

def lista_vagas(request):
    createVaga = createVagaForm(request.POST or None)
    if createVaga.is_valid():
        createVaga.save()
    return redirect('home')
```

Comment: Infelizmente a sua pergunta está vaga. Por favor descreva a sua dúvida de forma objetiva.

Answer (score 0):

Para implementar um campo `choices` no **Django**, você deve primeiro adicionar um campo do tipo `CharField` com o parâmetro `choices` na sua classe de modelo. O parâmetro `choices` deve ser uma **tupla de tuplas**, onde cada tupla interna possui dois elementos: o primeiro é o valor que será armazenado no banco de dados e o segundo é a representação humanizada deste valor.

## Por exemplo, se você quiser implementar uma escolha de faixas salariais, poderia fazer algo como:

```
class vagaDeEmprego(models.Model):
    nameJob = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    faixa_salarial = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=(
        ('R$1.000', 'R$1.000'),
        ('R$1.000 a R$2.000', 'R$1.000 a R$2.000'),
        ('R$2.000 a R$3.000', 'R$2.000 a R$3.000'),
        ('Acima de R$3.000', 'Acima de R$3.000'),
    ))
```

Para exibir os valores das escolhas no template, basta usar o atributo `get_FOO_display` do objeto do modelo, onde `FOO` é o nome do campo. No caso do exemplo acima, ficaria:

```
{{ vaga.get_faixa_salarial_display }}
```

Isso irá exibir a representação humanizada da escolha armazenada no banco de dados.

No seu código, você está criando uma classe de formulário `FaixaSalarialChoice` com um campo de escolhas, mas este formulário não está sendo usado em lugar algum. Além disso, no template '**createVaga.html**', você está tentando exibir o formulário `FaixaSalarialChoice` e não o valor da escolha armazenado no banco de dados.

Uma forma de resolver isso seria remover a classe `FaixaSalarialChoice` e adicionar o campo `faixa_salarial` ao formulário '**createVagaForm**' e exibir o valor da escolha usando o atributo `get_FOO_display` mencionado acima.

## █████ Veja como ficaria o código █████

## **forms.py**

```
class createVagaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = vagaDeEmprego
        fields = [
            "nameJob",
            "faixa_salarial",
        ]
```

## **createVaga.html**

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="col-6 mt-4 m
```

Com isso, a classe `createVagaForm` já está pronta para ser usada em um formulário, no template '**createVaga.html**' e o valor da escolha de faixa salarial pode ser exibido usando o atributo `get_faixa_salarial_display` do objeto do modelo.

## O formulário no template ficaria assim:

```
<form name="createVaga" id="createVaga" method="post" action="/lista_vagas/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ createVagaForm.as_p }}
    <input class="btn btn-success mt-4" type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
</form>
```

## Para exibir o valor da escolha de faixa salarial no template, basta usar:

```
{{ vaga.get_faixa_salarial_display }}
```

Lembre-se de que esses exemplos assumem que o objeto `vaga` foi passado para o template como contexto e que o campo `faixa_salarial` foi preenchido com um valor válido.